# how to access Angular2 component specific data in console?

Tags: debugging, console, angular

Is there any way to access Angular2 specific component specific data in console, for debugging purpose?

Like Angular1 has capability to access its components value in console.

Comment: This is probably not what you're looking for, but I still find it useful to just use `console.log(JSON.stringify(this))` sometimes.

Comment: Thanks @Mark , will check that..do you wanted to put that console in my console in component class? Don't get me wrong, just asking.

Comment: Put it in whatever method gives you the visibility you need: in the component's constructor, in ngOnInit(), in ngOnChanges(), in an event handler, etc.

Comment: I know that i can get component context by console.log(this).. But how can i access component context from browser console. Though I'll try you suggestion. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

**update 4.0.0**

[**StackBlitz example**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dvxctt)

**update RC.1**

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/dkSQ9Qu4gHoftYcRAwW8?p=preview) In the browser console on the top-left (filter symbol) select `plunkerPreviewTarget` (or launch the demo app in its own window) then enter for example

Select a component in the DOM node and execute in the console

```
ng.probe($0);
```

or for IE - thanks to Kris Hollenbeck (see comments)

```
ng.probe(document.getElementById('myComponentId')).componentInstance
```

**Alternative**

*Hint: enabling debug tools overrides `ng.probe()`*

Enable debug tools like:

```
import {enableDebugTools} from '@angular/platform-browser';

bootstrap(App, []).then(appRef => enableDebugTools(appRef))
```

Use above Plunker example and in the console execute for example:

- `ng.profiler.appRef`
- `ng.profiler.appRef._rootComponents[0].instance`
- `ng.profiler.appRef._rootComponents[0].hostView.internalView`
- `ng.profiler.appRef._rootComponents[0].hostView.internalView.viewChildren[0].viewChildren`

I haven't found a way yet to investigate the `Bar` directive.

A better debug experience is provided by Augury which builds on this API

- https://augury.angular.io/
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b1YV9vJKXEA

**original (beta)**

Here is a summary how to do that <strike>https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/TOOLS_JS.md</strike> (*dead link and I haven't found a replacement*).

**Enabling debug tools**

By default the debug tools are disabled. You can enable debug tools as follows:

```
import {enableDebugTools} from 'angular2/platform/browser';

bootstrap(Application).then((appRef) => {
  enableDebugTools(appRef);
});
```

**Using debug tools**

In the browser open the developer console (Ctrl + Shift + j in Chrome). The top level object is called ng and contains more specific tools inside it.

Example:

```
ng.profiler.timeChangeDetection();
```

See also

- [Angular 2: How enable debugging in angular2 from browser console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41765245/angular-2-how-enable-debugging-in-angular2-from-browser-console/41765296?noredirect=1#comment70721927_41765296)

Comment: I investigated more and found out the hard way what's mentioned here https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/3689#issuecomment-181020512 (see also this pending PR https://github.com/angular/angular/commit/e1bf3d33f8a1fa05a832b9b7ee1300ef9862fd0b)

Comment: This issue is probably also related https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7045

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, it appears your updated **[Plnkr here](https://plnkr.co/edit/dkSQ9Qu4gHoftYcRAwW8?p=preview)** isn't working...

Comment: @Chris22 thanks for reporting. I recreated the example in StackBlitz

Comment: Might be worth mentioning the IE way as well. `ng.probe(document.getElementById('myComponentId')).componentInstance`

Comment: great answer, thank you @GünterZöchbauer! But the link is dead: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/TOOLS_JS.md

Comment: @Lonely thanks. I haven't found out where it went. I made it clear in my answer that the link is now dead.

Comment: I'm working with an Angular app and Chrome insists that e.g. `ng.probe($0)` or `ng.probe(document.querySelector("#elementId"))` return `null`. `angular` is completely `undefined`. What am I missing?

Comment: @Raketenolli I haven't worked with Angular since quite some time and don't know. They might have changed something since I posted this answer.

Comment: ng.probe is undefined. This is what worked for me: ng.getComponent(document.getElementsByTagName('TAGNAME')[0])
This gave me access to the public functions on that component.

Answer (score 34):

First select the element using chrome 'inspect element' and run below method in chrome 'developer console'.

```
ng.probe($0).componentInstance
```

You could also use a css selector as shown below.

```
ng.probe($$('.image-picker')[0]).componentInstance
```

If you do it often, to make it little easier, have a global shortcut created as below.  Now  select any DOM element inside the component using 'inspect element' and invoke 'e()' from console

```
window['e'] = () => eval('ng.probe($0).componentInstance');
```

Comment: Works with 5.2.0 as of today. Might not have been the case in the past though.

Comment: Does this work in production? I'm trying to do do ng.prove($0) on angular v7.2.7 app in production and it just returns null

Comment: @doublea this does not work in production. For production mode this answer may be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68113807/23715

Comment: In Angular 9+, use `ng.getComponent($0);` (https://stackoverflow.com/a/60539678/11991371)

Answer (score 12):

Using global scope variable.(any browser)

In `ngOnInit()` of component file

```
ngOnInit() {
   window['test'] = this;
   
}
```

Now we can access instance of that component including services(imported on that component).

If you want to prevent accessing `test` for let's say production, you can conditionally give access to `test` like:

```
constructor(private _configService: ConfigService) {
}
ngOnInit() {
   if(_configService.prod) {
      window['test'] = this;
   }
   
}
```

Here `_configService` means the instance of service used by all components and services.
So variable would be set like:

```
export class ConfigService {
   prod = false;
}
```

Comment: what I like about this is that uses the simplest possible way... too bad we have to TS, it would be even simpler

Comment: The problem with this solution is that you have to recompile the code. Not very good for debugging in process. Also a component can have more than one instanse on the page.

Answer (score 3):

I'm surprised that no one has mentioned Augury here, it's a Chrome plugin that gives you convenient access to all the information in your components, and also makes it easier to see that information in the console directly:

https://augury.rangle.io/

Comment: It uses Google Tag Manager, i. e. it spies on you.

Answer (score 1):

**Angular 9+:**

Select component root element in developer tools (Inspector), then type in console:

```
ng.getComponent($0);
```