# What is the read parameter in @ViewChild for

Tags: angular

Need help to understand meaning of {read: ViewContainerRef} in following statement.

```
@ViewChild('myname', {read: ViewContainerRef}) target;
```

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35209681/5612697)

Answer (score 156, accepted):

There can be several instances of various types associated with the element tag with the `#myname` template variable.

For each element there is an `ElementRef` and `ViewContainerRef` (maybe others from components or directives applied to that tag).

If the element is a component, then there is the component instance.

There can also be one or several directives applied to the element

With `{read: SomeType}` you tell what type should be returned from the element with the `#myname` template variable.

If you don't provide the `read` parameter, `@ViewChild()` returns the

- `ElementRef` instance if there is no component applied, or the
- component instance if there is.
- If you want to get something different you need to explicitly specify using `read`.

See also [How can I select an element in a component template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32693061/angular-2-typescript-get-hold-of-an-element-in-the-template)

Comment: 'maybe others from components or directives applied to that tag' : How can we get the full list of possible type ?

Comment: The directives and components listed in `directives: [...]` of the current component or in `PLATFORM_DITECTIVES` where a selectors matches.  You can use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35233572/how-to-access-angular2-component-specific-data-in-console/35233711#35233711 to investigate on a running application.

Comment: Ho so it's only one of ```ElementRef```, ```ViewContainerRef``` or ```Directive```, with components and directives defined by user just being sub-types of ```Directive``` ? I was thinking about other types, not sub-types defined by user  like directives. For instance injecting directly the ```HTMLElement``` instead of the ```ElementRef```.

Comment: This only supports Angular types that are associated with a node. `HTMLElement` is not one of them. `ElementRef` allows to access the HTMLElement using `ElementRef.nativeElement.

Comment: You are awesome. How did you figure this out?

Comment: Just trying all kind of things and investigating the Angular2 source.

Comment: How can I get what i want, when I pass element to the function on that element?
eg: <component #myElem (click)="someMethod(#myElem)">. How to get ElementRef in that method instead of component?

Comment: You can't when the element is a component. You can only specify what you want if you use `@ViewChild(... read: ElementRef) ...`

Comment: Just wondering. If I do it like `@ViewChild('form', {static: false}) public form: NgForm;` is angular also reading the type hint like the injector does? Or not? and is it faster to always add the read option? or is it actually slower?