# How do you call closePanel in angular 4 autoComplete material

Tags: angular, angular-material2

```
import { MdAutocomplete } from '@angular/material';

@Component({
 template:'
             <input type="text" [mdAutocomplete]="auto"/>
             <md-autocomplete #auto="mdAutocomplete" #autoComplete>
             <md-option>
               Some Options
             </md-option>
          </md-autocomplete>'
})

export class AutoComplete {
 @ViewChild('autoComplete') autoComplete: MdAutocomplete;

 closeAuto() {
   this.autoComplete.closePanel();
 }
}
```

It is not the complete code but the idea is to call closePanel inside a method. closePanel is listed as a method on https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/api but it fails to work. It says method not found.

tried this approach too

```
import { MdAutocompleteTrigger } from '@angular/material';

@Component({
 template:'
             <input #autoCompleteInput type="text" [mdAutocomplete]="auto"/>
             <md-autocomplete #auto="mdAutocomplete" #autoComplete>
             <md-option>
               Some Options
             </md-option>
          </md-autocomplete>'
})

export class AutoComplete {
 @ViewChild('autoCompleteInput') autoComplete: MdAutocompleteTrigger;

 closeAuto() {
   this.autoComplete.closePanel();
 }
}
```

Comment: I've been running into a lot of methods and inputs that don't seem to be connected. I'd suggest opening an issue on the github repo https://github.com/angular/material2/issues

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Angular reads `ElementRef` by default from html element if you don't specify `read` option.

So

**template**

```
<input #autoCompleteInput type="text" [matAutocomplete]="auto"/>
```

**component**

```
@ViewChild('autoCompleteInput', { read: MatAutocompleteTrigger }) 
autoComplete: MatAutocompleteTrigger;
```

Here is the [**Plunker Example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/p6HbA5KeNnUzL0ZXA3AY?p=preview) that demonstrates this approach.

Comment: Explanation of the `read` property from Günter Zöchbauer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37476195/968003). Basically, we strongly type an element, which otherwise would have appeared as `ElementRef `

Comment: Just note MdAutocompleteTrigger is now MatAutocompleteTrigger.

Comment: This also helped me when targeting a component to make the dropdown open on focus: `this.autoComplete._onChange(''); this.autoComplete.openPanel();`

Comment: If you use multiple autocompletes with the same tag use `@ViewChildren(MatAutocompleteTrigger) autoComplete: QueryList<MatAutocompleteTrigger>;` and loop it. I use **id** of **input** to match. `if (this.autoComplete['_results'][i]['_element']['nativeElement']['id'] === _fieldid) {`

Comment: Great answer. Although the Angular docs mention this method, there is no example of how to use it. This is a common problem with Angular docs, in general.

Comment: If you have a just 2 autocompletes on your view, the easier method is to call "first" and "last" methods on the QueryList to get a reference to the panel. 
                         "this.autocomplete.last.closePanel();"