# Reopen Angular Material autocomplete on clear

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have an input `instructorControl = new FormControl();` with an autocomplete. The autocompelte subscribes to `this.instructorControl.valueChanges`.
When a suggestion from the autocomplete is selected or the add button is clicked, the current input value is pushed to an array and the input cleared with `this.instructorControl.patchValue('');`.

When an autocomplete option is selected, the autocomplete options menu is *not* opened again. For that, you either have to type something in or refocus the input.

How can I make the autocomplete reopen, when a suggestion is selected?

See this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x6hftl?file=app/autocomplete-overview-example.html). (Updated Sep 18)

#### app.component.html

```xml
  <button md-button (click)="addInstructor()">add</button>
  <md-input-container fxFlex>
    <input mdInput name="instructor" placeholder="instructor" (keydown.enter)="addInstructor()" [mdAutocomplete]="instructorsAuto" [formControl]="instructorControl">
  </md-input-container>


  <md-autocomplete #instructorsAuto="mdAutocomplete">
    <md-option *ngFor="let instructor of filteredInstructors | async" [value]="instructor" (click)="addInstructor()">
      {{ instructor }}
    </md-option>
  </md-autocomplete>

  {{instructors | json}}
```

#### app.component.ts

```js
  instructors: string[] = [];
  instructorControl = new FormControl();
  filteredInstructors: Observable<string[]>;
  allInstructors = ['Max', 'Tirrell'];;
  instructorsAuto;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.filteredInstructors = this.instructorControl.valueChanges
      .startWith('')
      .map(value => this.filterInstructors(value));
  }

  addInstructor() {
    const instructor: string = this.instructorControl.value;
    if (instructor) {
      this.instructors.push(instructor);
      this.instructorControl.patchValue('');
    }
  }

  private filterInstructors(value: string = ''): string[] {
    return this.allInstructors.filter(instructor => new RegExp(`${value}`, 'gi').test(instructor));
```

Comment: I updated the plunker from yurzui's answer in this stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x6hftl-fuxf8s?file=app/autocomplete-overview-example.ts

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My suggestion is using `@ViewChild` decorator to get hold of `MdAutocompleteTrigger` instance and then fire `openPanel()` method on it.

In order to do this:

1) Add template reference variable to `input[autocomplete]` element:

```html
<input #trigger ...
       [mdAutocomplete]="instructorsAuto"
       [formControl]="instructorControl">
```

2) Declare decorated by `@ViewChild` property.

```typescript
import { MdAutocompleteTrigger } from '@angular/material'
...
@ViewChild('trigger', { read: MdAutocompleteTrigger }) trigger: MdAutocompleteTrigger;
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
         make sure you're getting the right instance from template reference
```

3) Use it in your `addInstructor` method:

```typescript
this.trigger.openPanel();
```

**[Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x6hftl-fuxf8s?file=app/autocomplete-overview-example.ts)** (Updated Sep 2018)

Comment: Explanation of the `read` property from Günter Zöchbauer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37476195/968003). Basically, we strongly type an element, which otherwise would have appeared as `ElementRef `

Comment: @AlexKlaus Explanation of the read property from yurzui https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39908967/how-to-get-reference-of-the-component-associated-with-elementref-in-angular-2/39909203#39909203

Comment: Thank you @yurzui! BTW, do you know how to pass a reference to the `trigger` element to a function from the HTML and still be able to call `MdAutocompleteTrigger`'s method? E.g. for `<md-error *ngIf="!validate(trigger)"> Panic! </md-error>` and `function validate(auto: MdAutocompleteTrigger) { /* auto is just ElementRef here! */ }`

Comment: @AlexKlaus `triggerEl`  is `HTMLInputElement` while `trigger` is directive instance https://plnkr.co/edit/KlHOLhrqfw9XLWNd89y9?p=preview

Comment: hey @yurzui your sample is broken now, I couldn't figure out how can you open the trigger manually, for me it seems that it needs a small delay due the fact that when clicking in a element listed on it, when it hits the open line, it is still open so do nothing and then it close it as normal behaviour. Putting a setTimeout looks dirty I wonder if there is a better way. Thanks!

Comment: @AlejandroLora Updated example https://plnkr.co/edit/h52cDvfZF1XOHtEdztWe?p=preview

Comment: @yurzui What about triggering `optionSelected`  event programmaticallay using `@ViewChild` etc?