# Angular 2 injector hierarchy and NgModule

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, dependency-injection

I wonder how `NgModule` actually affects Angular 2 injector hierarchy.

What does the hierarchy look like in an app with nested modules? Does it create a new injector instance per each module or gets access to top-level injector (similarly to Angular 1.x modules)?

It can be somewhat confusing to figure out the tree in a big app.

Is there a way to print out, inspect or explore visually the hierarchy of injectors (like it could be done for scope hierarchy in Angular 1.x)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the Modules documentation: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html

> Angular registers these providers with the root injector of the module's execution context. That's the application's root injector for all modules loaded when the application starts.
>
> Angular can inject one of these provider services into any component
>   in the application. If this module provides the HeroService, or any
>   module loaded at launch provides the HeroService, Angular can inject
>   the same HeroService intance into any app component.
>
> A lazy loaded module has its own sub-root injector which typically is
>   a direct child of the application root injector.
>
> Lazy loaded services are scoped to the lazy module's injector. If a
>   lazy loaded module also provides the HeroService, any component
>   created within that module's context (e.g., by router navigation) gets
>   the local instance of the service, not the instance in the root
>   application injector.
>
> Components in external modules continue to receive the instance
>   created for the application root.

So, you have one injector that is shared between all the modules. However, lazy-loaded components will have a child injector

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to investigate providers using `ng.probe($0)` in the browser console. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/35233711/217408.

You can load modules with `MyModule.forRoot()` (see also https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html#!#providers) to get providers added at the root level.

If you provide it in a module, then it's available to the components in this module. I haven't seen it mentioned that a module introduces a child injector explicitly but to me this looks like it has to be the case.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to your another answer. Indeed, it answers the second part of the question.