# Get Service instance via console

Tags: angular

In Angular 1, you could get the injector via the console, which allowed you to then get any service:

```
angular.element(document.querySelector('html')).injector().get('MyService')
```

This was extremely useful for debugging. What's the equivalent in NG2?

Answer (score 5):

You can use `ng.probe($0)` in the console to get debug information about your Angular2 application.

See also [how to access Angular2 component specific data in console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35233572/how-to-access-angular2-component-specific-data-in-console/35233711#35233711)

But that is not available when `enableProdMode()` was called (only for debuggin)

Comment: I investigated a bit a while ago and was able to find providers as well. Not sure if you can get service instances from them.