# Calling Angular2 Component methods from Console in Production mode

Tags: angular

Is there a way to call component or service methods in Production mode?

I know an application can be debugged using `ng.probe` and with the Angular2 debugging app Augury: https://augury.angular.io/

However, these only works when in development mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no built-in method, to my knowledge.

This can be handled by custom flag in URL hash

```
import {enableProdMode} from '@angular/core';
import {platformBrowserDynamic} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

const DEV_MODE = 'DEV_MODE';
const DEV_MODE_REGEXP = new RegExp('(?:^|;)' + DEV_MODE + '$');

const IS_DEV_MODE = DEV_MODE_REGEXP.test(window.location.hash);

if (window.ENV !== 'prod' || IS_DEV_MODE) {
  if (IS_DEV_MODE) {
    window.location.hash = window.location.hash.replace(DEV_MODE_REGEXP, '');
  }
} else {
  enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(...);
```

Or by putting a flag into `window.name`, like it was done in [`reloadWithDebugInfo`](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.5.8/src/Angular.js#L1736-L1739) in AngularJS.

Answer (score 5):

Here is how you can access the component object from console in production mode (at least in Angular 9).

First you need to find the HTML element, which corresponds to the Angular component. You can use something like `window.getAllAngularRootElements()[0].getElementsByTagName('my-component-tag')[0]`. Or you can also first find and select the component in the Inspector tool and then use the special variable `$0`.

Then, if this element corresponds to some Angular component, then it will have a special `__ngContext__` property attached. It contains an array of different component's properties used by Angular. One of the array's items is the component object itself. The index of the item may be different, so you'll need to examine the `__ngContext__` array yourself to find it.

I.e., briefly, do something like:

```
o = window.getAllAngularRootElements()[0].getElementsByTagName('my-component-tag')[0].__ngContext__[42];
```

(assuming 42 is the correct index in your case) and then use the `o` variable as needed.

Answer (score -1):

You're part way there already :) 
You can access the componentInstance with `ng.probe($0).componentInstance`

from there you can use public functions and alter variables, you just need to invoke the change detection when you do with the function below

`ng.probe($0)._debugInfo._view.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges()`

I took this from http://juristr.com/blog/2016/02/debugging-angular2-console/ if you want to read more :)

Comment: I just noticed you were trying to do this outside of development mode - Unfortunately, part of enabling prod mode, disables the development tools used above. It has to be done in dev

Comment: Exactly! Looking for something similar to allow me to eg. toggle some flags, change logging level in my application from the console

Answer (score -1):

You can reproduce the same in lower env, then debug.

ng.probe($('component_tag-name')).componentInstance.fn()

to use $0, you will need to expand the element first, otherwise console will tell you $0 undefined.

Comment: The ng variable is only accessible in development mode. The question is about production mode.