# Call function from browser console in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a function inside an Angular component,lets say:

```
setDevMode(mode:string):void {
    this.devMode = mode;
}
```

How would I go about running it from the browser console?

Comment: or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40809192/calling-angular2-component-methods-from-console-in-production-mode

Comment: Tried both, but they are outdated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To call a *method* from a component instance, you need to get a reference to the component instance. You can do that in Angular 9+ with the `ng` global variable, by using its `getComponent` function.

In order to use this, you need to have access to the html element created by your component instance. You can find it in the Elements tab in Chrome ("Inspector" in firefox), right click on the element and choose "Store as global variable" ("Use in console" in firefox). You now have a variable in the console that you can send to the `getComponent` function, for example `temp1`:

```
const myCompInstance = ng.getComponent(temp1)
```

With this, you can now call the method like this:

```
myCompInstance.setDevMode("some_mode")
```

Notice that you will probably have to run `ng.applyChanges` on the element to see the UI update, like this:

```
ng.applyChanges(temp1)
```

Answer (score 1):

If this function is inside a closure, Then you can't call from the console.

Otherwise, you just do `functionName();` and hit return.

Comment: Sorry, I should have made more clear that the function is inside an angular component instance.

Comment: @gabrielsalvador "functions" inside classes are usually called methods, they aren't referred to as functions since they are bound to the instance of the class they're in and are used to change the state of that instance. That said, you should be able to get the component instance with `ng.getComponent(*htmlElement*)`. With that instance, you can call the methods. https://angular.io/api/core/global/ngGetComponent

Comment: this solved it, thank you for the clarification.
I've marked your answer as correct, please update it with the specifics for angular

Comment: @gabrielsalvador I created a new answer since I wasn't the author of this answer. Could you mark that one as accepted instead?