# What are `ng-reflect-...` attributes added by `angular2` to DOM?

Tags: angular

I've inspected the DOM elements for my components and they have `ng-reflect-...` attributes. For example,

```
<my-table ng-reflect-products="[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]" ng-reflect-display-entries-count="2"><table _ngcontent-cew-1="" class="table table-striped">
```

And the component is defined as:

```
export class MyTableComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() products: Array<Product>;
```

What are these `ng-reflect-...` attributes? Can they be helpful for me during debugging?

Comment: I think http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35233572/how-to-access-angular2-component-specific-data-in-console/35233711#35233711 will provided better information for debugging.

Comment: thanks, I'll take a look

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer My angular histery starts to reach a new height. This time, angular4 (said "compatible" with 2.4) produces mystical effects, maybe you could take a look to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43397839/1783163) question, it got 2 ups from 15 views. Note, our project is considering a switch to react.