# Protractor tests failing in second run for ng-reflect attribute

Tags: angular, protractor, e2e-testing

I have a bunch of Protractor tests for for e2e of a web application. There are a lot of input boxes , and a majority of them have `ng-reflect-name` attribute generated due to the underlying Angular4 code. Here is an example HTML snippet

```
  <input _ngcontent-c6="" class="input ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-invalid ui-inputtext 
  ui-corner-all ui-state-default ui-widget" formcontrolname="email" pinputtext="" 
  placeholder="Enter Email Address" spellcheck="false" type="text" ng-reflect-name="email">
```

My issue is regarding the use of locator in this. If I use this code for this specific input box  -

```
 element(by.css('[formcontrolname='email']'))
```

and perform any `sendKeys()`operation, it works out completely fine.

However, if I use this locator

```
 element(by.css('[ng-reflect-name="email"]'))
```

my tests run for the successfully for the first time, but errors out giving a  `NoSuchElementException` for the subsequent runs. I have searched on SO and the Angular docs, but I can't seem to explain why this happens. If anyone has faced this issue before, can you explain what is happening here?

Answer (score 4):

Since `ng-reflect-*` are there [for debugging purposes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43397839/what-does-the-ng-reflect-attribute-do-in-angular2-4), *I would not rely locators on them*.

I suspect [the function that adds `ng-reflect-*` attributes](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/core/src/view/services.ts#L234) does not necessarily perform before Angular confirms "readiness" to Protractor (every Protractor "command" goes through a sync with Angular). In other words, at the time you search for your input, `ng-reflect-name` is not yet set on the element.

If you are still going to continue using `ng-reflect-*` attributes, try adding an [Explicit Wait](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.wait) to wait for the element to become present:

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
var emailInput = element(by.css('[ng-reflect-name=email]'));
browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(emailInput), 5000);

emailInput.sendKeys("test@test.com")
```

Comment: Hmm. the debugging point that you made is new to me, so I'll keep that in mind. I'm not sure about the wait part, because I have used explicit wait to wait for almost 20 seconds and it fails even though. Also other locators that I have used using `ng-reflect-* don't have this issue.

Comment: @demouser123 hm, thanks, than my hypothesis is not correct..it was so beautiful though :)..are you sure the element is actually there? Recheck if you are on the page you think you are..

Comment: Yeah. I'm pretty sure that I'm on the page that I would want it to be.

Comment: this should be the accepted answer. Thanks