# how do i capture the value of ng-reflect-value to test against its expected value?

Tags: angular, selenium, protractor

Per the attachment, I'm using this statement "**private readonly By _idTxt = By.XPath(".//*[@class='metric-set-details-dropdown']/../button[ng-reflect-value]");**" in hope of capturing the value for the attribute **ng-reflect-value** for an assert test but my test run is failing with "OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException : *no such element: Unable to locate element*: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//*[@class='metric-set-details-dropdown']/../button[ng-reflect-value]"}"

Any input is appreciated!

Thanks,
Tien[image]

Answer (score 2):

FYI you should not rely on `ng-reflect-*` since angular add these attributes only for debugging purpose.
Still if you need it, then see:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44469527/9709887

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.  I'm very new at this and glad to learn that ng-reflect-* is meant for debugging only.  The developer used to provide the value I needed with <span _ngcontent-22 class="metricId">xxxxxxx</span> with which an earlier test with By.XPath(".//*[@class='metricId']") worked.  Since changes to the UI has the metric ID now in ng-reflect-value, I'll figure a different way of acquiring the value for my assert test.  Thanks again for your help!