# How do I select an Ng-reflect-index selector on Protractor?

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I'm programming an end-to-end test for my website, but I cannot select my element.

[image: snippet]

Comment: You can try `element(by.css('[ng-reflect-index="2"]'))`;

Comment: Ooooh yes ! it's working! thank you

Comment: I have added this as an answer. If your issue was resolved, please accept this as an answer :) #SOReadyToHelp

Comment: By voting? Sorry i m new

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this...

```
element(by.css('[ng-reflect-index="2"]'))
```

However `ng-reflect-*` are used for [debugging purposes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43397839/what-does-the-ng-reflect-attribute-do-in-angular2-4) (thanks, [@alexce](https://stackoverflow.com/users/771848/alecxe), for this piece of information). So you shouldn't really rely on them in your tests.