# How can a custom attribute of a component be accessed? (Angular 5)

Tags: javascript, angular, dom, angular5

I've got a component called phrase, which is used like this:

```
<phrase *ngFor="let phrase of phraseList.phrases" [attachedPhrase]="phrase"></phrase>
```

Let's say now, I get one of these phrase components using jQuery. How do I access `attachedPhrase`?

Comment: Here you are using ngFor. My question is if you just want to get a specific one or all ?

Comment: The specific one that belongs to this element.

Comment: There are ViewChild, ElementRef and attr() that you can use. I can help you providing a good answer but Can you provide a clear use case ?

Comment: My application unfortunately makes use of some dirty jquery on keyboard events to return the phrase component I'm interested in. https://imgur.com/GghcsKt,

Now, I need to use that DOM element to get the phrase object attached to it.

Answer (score 2):

`[attachedPhrase]` is not an attribute but [property binding](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#property-binding--property-). It is supposed to be available only inside Angular application.

Although it's possible to access it as [`ng-reflect-*` attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43397839/what-does-the-ng-reflect-attribute-do-in-angular2-4), this can be recommended only for debugging purposes (this is the reason why these attributes are available in *debugging mode* only).

Considering that `phrase` is a string and `attachedPhrase` should be available both as component input and DOM attribute, it should be changed to [attribute binding](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#attribute-binding):

```
<phrase *ngFor="let phrase of phraseList.phrases" attachedPhrase="{{ phrase }}"></phrase>
```

Since attributes are case insensitive, it will be compiled to

```
<phrase attachedphrase="..."></phrase>
```

Property and attribute bindings can be interchangeable, but only if the expression is expected to be interpolated to a string.

Whenever possible, it's always preferable to not rely on DOM selectors and provide `$(...)` with actual reference to DOM element (`nativeElement` property of `ViewChild` or `ElementRef` element reference).

Comment: phrase isn't a string though. It's an object. Will this still work?

Comment: No. DOM attributes cannot be objects, they are strings. You should reconsider the way you're integrating the component with jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

You can try: `[attr.attachedPhrase]="'phase'"`.

Detailed info you can check out [this site](https://www.concretepage.com/angular-2/angular-2-custom-attribute-directive-example) about Angular 5 directive.