# Ionic Build creates DIV where non existed?

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, ionic3

I've been searching around and I can't find for the life of me where an extra div is being created... the only reason we care is that it's bringing a mid tone grey background color over the Nav bar and it's killing the look of our app.

Hoping for a bit of guidance, happy to post up any relevant code needed; nothing in home stands out (extra div shows up everywhere, so I'm guessing it's not in a single pages worth of css/html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be worthwhile removing all classes from the navbar area, and then adding them back one by one and seeing which one/s cause the problem. Also check the Ionic documentation [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/) to see if there's something else to check out.

Comment: Awesome, which file should I look to for that? Home.ts?


Thank you!

Comment: One thing that I just noticed is that upon a new ionic serve being started, the toolbar-background-wp (windows phone, right?) changed to toolbar-background-md...

That's Android, correct? I'm just trying to help out our developer who recently inherited this project from a team that ditched us in mid-development.

Comment: reading up on this... and adding the Prod calls- there's less in there now, now it's just a singular div that's of the class "toolbar-background toolbar-background-md"

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43397839/what-does-the-ng-reflect-attribute-do-in-angular2-4

Comment: the change in "wp" to "md" seems to be because of my --lab or not --lab when calling ionic serve.

Still a bit perplexed where to look at removing the classes...