# How to set a dynamic "id" HTML attribute of an angular component?

Tags: javascript, angular, dependency-injection

My problem is related to placing the same component with different parameters on the same page. In this case it is a component containing a chart from a third party Javascript library ([D3JS](https://d3js.org/)) which needs an HTML `id` attribute to locate and modify the component's HTML contents.

Now this `id` attribute should contain a unique string for each chart placed on the page, and if I directly set it as a string from the parent component it works just fine:

`<my-chart id="gaugeChart0"></my-chart>`

The reason it works is I guess, because the `id` attribute exists right at component creation time and whatever code is trying to access it can do that right away.

However this chart is in turn embedded into a bootstrap 4 card layout, like so:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-5">
                        <my-chart id="gaugeChart0"></my-chart>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-7">
                        ... Some other widgets ...
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-5">
                        <my-chart id="gaugeChart1"></my-chart>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-7">
                        ... Some other widgets ...
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now to make it more convenient (and to easily bind to click events to the whole block etc.) I would like to extract the whole part beginning with `<div class="card">` into a new component.

Let's say I call this new component *WidgetContainerComponent* which contains the chart as well as the bootstrap card layout including the other widgets defined there.

The resulting code when using this wrapper component would be:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
        <widget-container chartId="gaugeChart0"></widget-container>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
        <widget-container chartId="gaugeChart1"></widget-container>
    </div>
</div>
```

In order for that to work the *WidgetContainerComponent* has an input field

`@Input() chartId: string;`

that can be set.

What I want to do then is to set the `id` attribute of the *MyChartComponent* to the string that has been set to `chartId`:

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-5">
                <my-chart [id]="chartId"></my-chart>
            </div>
            <div class="col-7">
                ... Some other widgets ...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But this does not work, as angular adds a prefix to the `id` attribute which results in something like `ng-reflect-id`.

I also tried setting the attribute with `[attr.id]` as described [here](https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-assign-dynamically-an-ID-attribute-to-an-element-in-Angular-6) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23655009/how-to-set-the-id-attribute-of-a-html-element-dynamically-with-angularjs-1-x):

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-5">
                <my-chart [attr.id]="chartId"></my-chart>
            </div>
            <div class="col-7">
                ... Some other widgets ...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This results in the *MyChartComponent* having a straight `id` attribute, but it seems to be only added at a later stage within the lifecycle of the component.

I also tried to initialize the chart within the *MyChartComponent* only in `ngOnInit` and `ngAfterContentInit`, but this does not work as well.

Any suggestions or ideas are very welcome!

Comment: < div id="{{myvariable}}" >

Comment: Hi, you mean writing `<my-chart id="{{chartId}}"></my-chart>` instead of `<my-chart [id]="chartId"></my-chart>`?  I already tried this before, also in this case the `id` attribute name gets prefixed with an `ng-reflect-` string which results in a `ng-reflect-id` attribute which is not recognized as an HTML id attribute. 
I think however that I already figured it out, I will post an answer later.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So I found a solution to this problem. The problem was twofold:

1. The first problem was related to the requirement of having a genuine `id` attribute in contrast to the attribute name prefixed with `ng-reflect-` by angular.

   What I didn't know is that from Angular 4, this prefix gets added to any attribute which is declared as an `@Input` variable for the component in development mode (for an in-depth explanation see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43397839/what-does-the-ng-reflect-attribute-do-in-angular2-4)).

   The solution to this problem was to write `[attr.id]=chartId` instead of `[id]=chartId`. The reason is that in this case I needed to set an *HTML Attribute*, however using the square brackets notation I created a *Property Binding*. In order to dynamically set an HTML Attribute via the property binding syntax you have to add the prefix `attr.` to the attribute's name.

   For a good overview regarding all valid binding syntaxes see the [Angular Docs](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#binding-syntax-an-overview). 
   Specifically to review how to do attribute binding see [this section](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#attribute-binding).
2. The second problem was that I tried to access the `id` attribute of the component when it has not yet been created. This problem is related to the lifecycle hooks of Angular, where there are different stages. For a good overview of Angular's lifecycle hooks, see [this page](https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/components/lifecycle-hooks/).

   Because I didn't know it myself in detail, I will elaborate it here shortly.

   Angular comes with a fixed set of lifecycle hooks which are called each time a component is set up and are also called in a predefined order. The hooks are defined as follows:

   1. constructor
   2. ngOnChanges
   3. ngOnInit
   4. ngDoCheck

      1. ngAfterContentInit
      2. ngAfterContentChecked
      3. ngAfterViewInit
      4. ngAfterViewChecked
   5. ngOnDestroy

   _

   Important to note is that elements created or prepared in one step can only be accessed in any of the subsequent steps. In my case I put all the code for the initialization of the chart into the `ngAfterContentInit` hook, however the component is only fully loaded when `ngAfterViewInit` is called.

   Finally the solution was to put the pre-initialization code into the constructor and to place the chart initialization code into the `ngAfterViewInit` method. At this stage the `id` attribute had been created properly and could be accessed by the chart.

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful! I was setting the id in constructor and doing getElementById in ngOnInit. Obviously the component was not fully initialized!

Comment: Great, glad it helped you!