# Property 'parentElement' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'

Tags: typescript, angular5

Development mede this work!!

Production mode this error!!

If you remove FocusEvent, the same error.

```
Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
at e.preSaveMac (main.bundle.js:1)
at Object.handleEvent (main.bundle.js:1)
at Object.handleEvent (main.bundle.js:1)
at Object.handleEvent (main.bundle.js:1)
at Ji (main.bundle.js:1)
at main.bundle.js:1
at t.r [as _next] (main.bundle.js:1)
at t.__tryOrUnsub (main.bundle.js:1)
at t.next (main.bundle.js:1)
at t._next (main.bundle.js:1)
```

`preSaveMac(event:FocusEvent){
    this.additionSearchMAC = event.srcElement.parentElement.attributes["ng-reflect-model"].value;
    $(event.srcElement).val(this.additionSearchMAC);
  }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ng-reflect-model` attribute is only rendered in development mode and it is only there for debugging purposes (see [What does the "ng-reflect-*" attribute do in Angular2/4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43397839/what-does-the-ng-reflect-attribute-do-in-angular2-4#answer-43473682) )

So you shouldn't try to access them in your application's code.

It appears you're trying to access the ngModel of either 1) the current component or 2) some parent component.
If 1), just directly use the variable you referenced in your template (e.g. `([ngModel])=myVar` means you can use `this.myVar` to access it in the component code)
If 2) Pass the `ngModel` downwards to the component yourusing this in with an `@Input()`.

Btw.: Setting a value to a form control using jquery's `val()` function in angular is most likely bad practice (If possible, use ngModel or a FormControl instead).

Comment: This is genius!