# Does binding to ngValue set a max length on the string value it holds?

Tags: angular

I have an `ngFor` directive bound to a list of objects with an option element. I bound the id property of the object to `ngValue` to be used later. The odd thing I've noticed is that when I get the value in the .ts file, part of the id is missing from the value I got from the database. When I use the `value` attribute instead, I get the whole id.

[image: You can see the last 6 characters missing in the ng-reflect]

The picture shows the difference between the two attributes in the last 6 characters.

Anyone know why this is happening? Is there something about `ng-reflect` that limits the length of a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Limit the size of the value as otherwise the DOM just gets polluted."
https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/core/src/util/ng_reflect.ts

Generally `ngValue` is used for objects.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose the answer may be here:
[What does the "ng-reflect-*" attribute do in Angular2/4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43397839/what-does-the-ng-reflect-attribute-do-in-angular2-4)

As for me the better way to store such kind of properties is using data-attribute:

```
<option [attr.data-id]="id"></option>
```