# Why do bindings type comments appear in Angular?

Tags: angular

I would like to know why comments like these appear in Angular and if there is a way to hide them?

```
</div>
<!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if-else": "[object Object]"
}-->
<div>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you give more details please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those allow development tools like the [DevTools Chrome extension](https://angular.io/guide/devtools) to help you debug your application. They're not present when you build for production. There's no reason (and no way) to remove them in debug mode.

You can see this in action with [this StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ngrksu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html). Notice how the comment references why the element is being shown (an `ngIf` binding is `true` or `false`).

The `ng-reflect` attributes can be disabled by enabling production mode. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43397839/what-does-the-ng-reflect-attribute-do-in-angular2-4) for more information about that.