# Angular2: What is ng.probe and ng.coreTokens?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am working on a project build on [Angular 2](https://angular.io). I am going through it's source code. I came across the following piece of code:

```
let _ng = (<any>window).ng;
(<any>window).ng.probe = _ng.probe;
(<any>window).ng.coreTokens = _ng.coreTokens;
```

I don't know what are `ng`, `ng.probe` and `ng.coreTokens` and for what purpose they are being used in angular 2. Can anyone please shed some lights on these? I googled these terms as well, but couldn't find any helpful elaboration.  I am new to the world of Angular 2. Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35233572/how-to-access-angular2-component-specific-data-in-console/35233711#35233711 https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/front-end-javascript/debugging-angular-2-applications

Comment: @yurzui Thanks for links. Pretty much helpful.

Comment: @HiteshKumar If you've found good info, you might want to answer your own question. Rep awaits, etc. ;)

Comment: @ruffin Please refer yurzui's comment. This question is already answered.

Comment: Hrm. I don't see an answer submitted. You've got nearly 1300 rep... You know how this site works! ;^D I was suggesting you distill that link into an answer, write it up below, and mark that "real" answer accepted -- then the community benefits (and this question will be marked answered within SO). Or perhaps @yurzui can be talked into doing that?