# Angular 2: How enable debugging in angular2 from browser console

Tags: angular, debugging

In [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/), we have a function called [`reloadWithDebugInfo()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.reloadWithDebugInfo)

```
angular.reloadWithDebugInfo()
```

which reload the current application with debug information turned on. One can execute this function in browser console and enable the debugging. I am looking for it's equivalent in [Angular 2](http://angular.io) which can let us enable debugging in developer console. But it seems like there's no equivalent function of this which can be accessed in the browser console. I know there are functions like `enableDebugTools` and `disableDebugTools` which let us enable and disable the debugging but one can not access them in browser console. And also to get access to angular2's debugging weapons like `ng` & `ng.probe`, one has to enable debug tools first as written in the [Angular 2 Application Debugging Guide](https://github.com/pluralsight/guides/blob/master/published/front-end-javascript/debugging-angular-2-applications/article.md):

> Make sure your application has production mode disabled so that you
>   can have access to the all the methods described below.

I just want to know **Is there any way to enable debug tool using console in Angular 2?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Debugging info is enabled by default during development in Angular2.

Debugging tools need to be enabled with [`enableDebugTools`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/platform-browser/index/enableDebugTools-function.html)

For production [`enableProdMode()`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/enableProdMode-function.html) should be called to get rid of debug information that slows down your application and increases code size.

For details how to access debug info from the console see [how to access Angular2 component specific data in console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35233572/how-to-access-angular2-component-specific-data-in-console/35233711#35233711)

https://augury.angular.io/ provides a browser Plugin with a graphical UI

Because an Angular application is built for deployment, the options need to be enabled when the application is built, otherwise it won't be included in the deployable.

Comment: How do I enable debugging in production once it is disabled.

Comment: You don't. You need to build it with debugging enabled. You need to actually enable it as you mentioned in your question (I was to update my answer but Chrome crashed). If your application is built with debugging disabled, there is no debugging information included in your deployable.

Comment: So we can not enable debugging in production. One has to rebuild with debugging enabled and then deploy. Makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, that's my understanding.