# Error in console: ng.probe is not a function

Tags: javascript, angular, debugging, angular-cli

Yesterday I updated Angular CLI and core to 8.0.0v. After that I successfully initialized a new app and ran it. Once the app was built and served on `localhost:4200` I opened the console and there was an error:

> ng.probe is not a function

I tried to research the issue, but there was no relevant info about it.

Actual result:

After `ng serve` / `npm start` there is an issue in the console:

> Uncaught TypeError: ng.probe is not a function. [Current console
> state](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/32274987/58589676-14960b80-826b-11e9-8c6d-adb1f141cef7.png)
> [Current angular
> state](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/32274987/58589626-ff20e180-826a-11e9-8c0c-3f88aaefad6b.png)

Expected result:

No error in the console

Comment: are you running angular in dev mode?

Comment: Yes it was set by default after ng new. Even more i debug my main.ts file to check envoirment and it was set to dev

Answer (score 50):

If someone is looking for an alternative to:

```
ng.probe($0)
```

In Ivy, then please try this:

```
 ng.getComponent($0);
```

Found it here, https://juristr.com/blog/2019/09/debugging-angular-ivy-console/

Thought I'd add this here for completion.

Note about `ng.getComponent`: you must focus the component tag ( e.g. `<app-my-component>` ) in the developer tools elements so that it will be in $0. It doesn't search up the hierarchy for parent components ( like `ng.probe` does ).

Comment: You can also save component instances in global variables and then use ng.getComponents(). Details are discussed here https://mobiarch.wordpress.com/2020/07/08/ng-probe-no-more/

Answer (score 33):

If you're using **Augury extension**, disable or remove it. then, check the console. I've had the same issue and I removed the Augury.

Augury is having different set of debugging APIs, that's why that error occur.

Comment: this is the cause of the problem

Comment: I removed mine and it's still doing it.

Comment: Maybe you're having a different problem than mine. you can try different solutions in this post as well

Answer (score 17):

Yes, augury assumes angular dev mode is active if window.ng exists, but ivy doesn't export probe right now

[image: angular ivy exports]
I have augury but after I disable the extension there is no error anymore.

Comment: Thanks! Can confirm, turning off Augury chrome extension removed that console error for me as well.

Comment: I can confirm also that the same problems happens with firefox. A removing the extensión solved it. :)

Comment: What is irritating is, that Augury does work for chrome by now. It just does not for Firefox.

Answer (score 7):

You could also run without Ivy with this in your `tsconfig.app.json`

```
"angularCompilerOptions": { "enableIvy": false }
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not exactly related to this question, but googling led me here. So, I am leaving the solution to my problem here in hopes that it will help others who face the same problem.

I was getting `ng.probe not a function` error when I created a **angular** project using **dotnet sdk(version 5.0.300)** and ran it locally. The project was using **@angular/core v8.2.12**, and **@angular/cli v8.3.29**.

I was able to solve the problem by update these packages using -

`ng update @angular/core@8 @angular/cli@8`

or

`npm run ng update @angular/core@8 @angular/cli@8`