# ng.probe() in console; Uncaught ReferenceError: ng is not defined

Tags: angular, debugging

I'm using Angular 11 via `ng serve` in Chrome. In the debug console, I write ng.probe($0) to debug and get:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: ng is not defined

Augury is installed. Dunno if that could be related. It's my first time trying to use ng in the console. I'm guessing it's something I need to set up, or maybe a legacy feature.

UPDATE: It's probably a breakpoint that I threw in there arbitrarily and don't remember exactly where it was. I didn't think so, but I didn't make any other changes, so... ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ Sorry.

Comment: check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56373044/error-in-console-ng-probe-is-not-a-function

Comment: Different issue. In that question `ng` is recognized, but its `.probe` function isn't. Here `ng` isn't defined.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably this happens when angular is not installed globally. Try to check.