# Is it possible to access the object value of Angular *ngFor with pure JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, angular

In Angular I have an `ngFor` loop iterating over an array of form groups. The loop looks like this:

```html
<div *ngFor="let fg of arrayOfFormGroups" [attr.fg]="fg">
</div>
```

Would it somehow be possible to access this `fg` with pure JavaScript? When I do the following in the Chrome console:

```js
nativeElement.attributes.getNamedItem('fg').value;
```

I only get `"[object Object]"` string value.

Is what I am trying to achieve possible?

The reason why this is relevant is that I'm developing keyboard navigation, and using the `nextElementSibling` attribute would make it a breeze, but I need to get hand of this `fg`.

Comment: is `fg` an object?

Comment: Are you integrating the Angular element in a pure JS context? If not you could try with template reference variables.

Comment: Yes, `fg` is an Angular Form Group. @MichaelD this question came up when brainstorming how to develop some navigation features, where the sibling attributes could be very useful (if I could access the attributes these native elements have)

Comment: See the answer for this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35233572/how-to-access-angular2-component-specific-data-in-console

Comment: Thanks for providing a link @EliasSoares, but I'm not interested in debugging here.

Comment: Is not debugging. You use ng.probe to get the component related to that element and directly access the value of the variable you want.

Comment: problem is that won't work in production.

Comment: You cannot store an object in an attribute, only a string. So you could do a JSON.stringify. But i’s probably better to rethink your approach.